# Eclipse using Android emulator

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

I wonder if anyone has faced the same problem.

When we done some modification on the code, as the emulator is running; is there any way we could see the instant change without closing the emulator?

Sometimes when I made changes on the code then run the emulator, the amendment that I made doesn't seem to show on the emulator even after I clean the project.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that Eclipse will not check if your files were altered outside of Eclipse before re-building the `.apk`. You have to manually refresh them. Don't know if that affects you though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has an option under 'Run' in the menu bar to build, and run. This will re-package the application and send it to either your AVD, or attached android phone.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly I wnat!